How to restore database file?
So I have a .odb file which for some unknown reason lost all its content. I was editing some entries in the DB and when I tried to save and close it, I wasn't able to. So I thought it was no big deal and decided to close it without saving with the expectation that only the latest changes I had made will be lost. But the next time I tried opening it I noticed it was sitting at 0 bytes. I am not sure if it was like that just before closing LibreOffice Base or no. Any idea how I can restore it if it's possible? Note that this wasn't a file I just created, but an old one which has been edited many times.

Won't help solve the problem, but: LibreOffice Base files with embedded setup can easily get corrupted when saving, because it must collapse the database each time. The recommendation I've always heard, if it's important to keep your data, is to use an external database setup instead, such as Base with PostgreSQL. Embedded is useful for quickly setting something up to copy into Calc for example. Otherwise, if embedded is required, then I guess save a lot of backup copies and keep checking to make sure the current file is still okay.

I'm glad you shared this. I was wondering if this was some anomaly or something that happens from time to time. Regarding the file it's probably unrecoverable as it was overwritten. But it wasn't a big database so no big deal.
